# My code is not woriking. am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c

I just have studied programming and english. I'm a newbie.

My code is supposed to show a sum of 1 to entered number.

(ex : if you enter 5, answer is 15 and if you enter 10, answer is 55)

Bu this code is not working. I have tried many times to fix it, but i don't know why this code is not working.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int i = 0;
    int sum;
    int j;

    scanf("%d\n", sum);
    for(j = 1; j <= sum; j++){

     i = i + j;}

    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass `&sum` to `scanf`, i.e. its address.  Otherwise `scanf` can't change it.  Your compiler should have warned about this.

Comment: You need to format your code as code (highlight it and click or tap the "{} icon). I fixed it for you. The `#include <stdio.h>` line was messed up; I corrected it, and I presume it matches what's in your source file. And when you post a question you need to tell us **how** it's not working. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: As @Tom pointed `scanf("%d\n", sum);` --> `scanf("%d", &sum);`

Comment: Also, drop the `\n` in the `scanf` format. It already waits for whitespace (space or newline) after reading the value of `sum`; no need to wait for another newline. Also, `sum` is a bad name for that variable, since it's not a sum.

Comment: As others above have pointed `\n` is the problem in the `scanf`. Please have a look at [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to debug better in the future before asking on SO.

Comment: ... At last, consider doing a little (high-school level algebra) math before coding: in your case, it is extremely relevant. Gauss was a genius, and is rumored to [have solved that problem](http://www.wbilljohnson.com/journal/math/gauss.htm) at the age of 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is a simple one, and a decent compiler will warn you about it:

```
testprog.c: In function ‘main’:
testprog.c:9:11: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’,
                          but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d\n", sum);
           ^
```

The `scanf` function requires the *address* of items you want populated since it needs to change them. Passing the actual item (since C is pass-by-value) to a function could only ever change the copy rather than the original.

You can see the correct way to do it in the standard:

> `d`: Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtol` function with the value 10 for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be a ***pointer*** to signed integer.

---

As an aside, I've fixed that issue and added some more improvements, such as:

- less confusing variable names (at no stage is your `sum` variable a sum of anything);
- better (more logical) layout of code;
- better scoping of temporary variables like `i`.
- prompting the user for input so that they know what they're supposed to enter; and
- checking for valid input by checking return value of `scanf`.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int maxNum;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter number to sum up to: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &maxNum) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Problem getting input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= maxNum; ++i) {
        sum += i;
    }

    printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

  int i = 0;
  int sum;
  int j;

  scanf("%d", &sum);
  for(j = 1; j <= sum; j++){

   i = i + j;}

  printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}
```

Your mistake is just wrote  scanf("%d\n", sum) instead of scanf("%d", &sum);

Comment: I appreciate you giving me the advice!

Answer (score 1):

c language supports a type of `call by value` what transfers data copied.
So, you need to give the memory address that `scanf` function can write user's input to the `sum` variable memory.

```
scanf("%d", &sum)
```